# I struggle with this for loop task

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm trying to create this only with **for** loops:

1
12
123
1234
12345

My code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++)
            {
                int counter = 1;
                Console.Write(counter);

                for(int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(counter + 1);

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

But I get this:
1
12
122
1222

and is there any way I can do it without the counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your internal `for` loop at little bit, remove `counter` variable and start a loop from `j` equals `1` till current value of `i` from external loop

```cs
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(j);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The reason, why your code doesn't work is that you set `counter` to `1` and didn't change its value anymore, and always use `counter + 1`, which prints `2`

Comment: I can approve it only after 10 minutes so I'll do that after the time will pass

Answer (score 1):

If you allow the use of a string, it can be done in 1 for loop:

```
string output = "";

for(int i = 1; i<5; i++){
  //Append new number
  output += i.ToString();
  //Output it
  Console.WriteLine(output);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

I am the first to admit that is not the most robust solution. You may want to use a `List<int>` for output. But with those, the output code is way more complciated. So I choose the string shortcut here.